# Simulation of Matcher#start(String) functionality in Java 7

Tags: java

In Java 8, a new `start(String)` method was introduced in `Matcher` class which returns the start index of the subsequence captured by the given named-capturing group during the previous match operation.

Is there any way to simulate this method's functionality in Java 7? The same question for `end(String)`, but it should be very similar.

I could not find any information about named groups neither in `Pattern` class public API nor in `Matcher` itself. I also looked at the implementation of `Pattern` class in Oracle JRE, and there is a `namedGroups` map inside of `Pattern` class that maps name of a named group to its index, but there seems to be no public API that interacts with this map in Java 7.

I am not looking for any kind of reflection solutions, but any kind of pattern and/or input string manipulations are fine.

Comment: Named groups are still numbered, so you should still be able to use `start(int)` and `end(int)` instead.

Comment: @4castle that's great, but how can I know the number of a group given its name?